# glsl dot function indirectly causing a segmentation fault in program

Tags: segmentation-fault, glsl, opengl-3, dot-product

Heres my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_normal;

//model space
uniform vec3 toLight;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

smooth out vec3 color;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0f);
  
  vec3 normal = normalize(vertex_normal);
  
  float intensity = dot(normal, toLight);
  intensity = clamp(intensity, 0, 1);
  
  color = vec3(intensity);
}
```

In this code I am trying to calculate lighting using the tutorial at [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming site](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2009.html). Which is a great book by the way, however the code here is basically identical to the listed code with a couple of names changed, however through the some experimentation, I have discovered something very peculiar. The segmentation fault occurs on the

> color = vec3(intensity);

line, I know that because removing that line causes the program to run normally, (except without lighting of course)

However when I replace the line

> float intensity = dot(normal, toLight);

with:

> float intensity = 3.14159;

It clamps to 1.0f and everything works fine, the cube is white, same happens if I put a negative number: the number is clamped to zero and the cube is black...

So this is strange, here's the facts:

- The segmentation fault disappears when removing the line that sets the output vector to the color requested.
- The segmentation fault also disappears when removing the calculation of the dot product
- When the intensity is a constant float, everything works fine.
- setting the color to anything *not involving the intensity* works fine.
- EDIT: found some interesting info, when setting a variable other than the color variable using the intensity variable works fine, for example `vec3 temp = vec3(intensity);` doesn't cause a segfault, however setting color to something that is not related to the intensity variable works fine also `color = vec3(1.0f);` although, if I were to set color to `temp` it would crash too, this is very strange.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Also, I would include my opengl, c++ code, but I don't think it's necessary, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you getting segfault at shader compile/link, or at shader runtime (glDraw...)? Are you checking compile/link result of your shader/program?

Comment: the segfault is at runtime when drawing using the glDrawElements function, compiling and linking works fine

Comment: I might try making use of the `isinf` and `isnan` GLSL functions to see if maybe an `inf` or `NaN` is sneaking into your calculations. I've had some issues before with NaN's in my GLSL code when hitting bugs like divide by zero, or trying to normalize a length zero vector, which caused the whole program to fail.

Comment: good idea, but I tested this just now by getting the shader to output a red color if the intensity isinf or isnan, it didn't turn red.

Comment: How about setting color equal to the values that derive the intensity calculation? Could be an interesting datapoint. Try `color = normal` or `color = toLight`. Or maybe `color = intensity_unclamped` (omit the clamp instruction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, god! I made a big mistake, right here:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_normal;
```

notice how `vertex_position` and `vertex_normal` have the same location, I didn't either. Setting the `vertex_normal` location to 1 fixed everything, sorry I wasted most of your time, but thanks to all of you for suggestions and to Tim who got me to realize that a segfault was occurring with the normal, leading me to the top of the source, thanks all of you just the same... =D

Answer (score 2):

Best guess: you have a bug in the code that sets the `toLight` uniform -- it looks something like `glUniform3fv(toLight_location, 3, pointer)`, but `pointer` is bogus (NULL or otherwise invalid).  The GL driver code tries to dereference this pointer and crashes.  When you remove all uses of `toLight` in the shader, it doesn't crash because `toLight_location` becomes -1 as its inactive and the `glUniform3fv` call becomes a noop.

Comment: Nah, I tried modifying the code to not calculate the dot product but used the toLight's componenet's as the color, everything works fine, also I using glUniform3f rather than glUniform3fv, good idea though, it's possible there might be some weird uniform data floatin' around, I'll look into that...